# Is there any way to run an onClick event before a formik onSubmit?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to create a login page with the following submit button

```
<Button
  color="primary"
  disabled={isSubmitting}
  fullWidth
  size="large"
  type="submit"
  variant="contained"
  onClick={() => { login(values.email, values.password); }}>
  Sign in
</Button>
```

The login logic looks like this

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    console.log('User: ', user);
    authenticated = true;
    console.log('Authenticated: ', authenticated);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
    authenticated = false;
  }
};
```

My formik component looks like this

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Must be a valid email').max(255).required('Email is required'),
    password: Yup.string().max(255).required('Password is required')
  })}
  onSubmit={() => {
    console.log('Authenticated: ', authenticated);
    if (authenticated === true) {
      navigate('/app/dashboard', { replace: true });
    }
  }}
>
```

My idea is to get the onClick of the submit button, to run the login logic before the onSubmit runs, this would set `authenticated` to `true` and allow the user to be redirected to Dashboard.js. Currently, it seems like the onSubmit runs before the onClick, causing `authenticated` to have it's default value of `false` and thus not redirecting the user to the Dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your login function is an async function, it returns a promise and hence the login inside onSubmit runs asynchronously.

You can call the `login` function inside `onSubmit` but have to wait for the promsie to fulfill

for example:

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Must be a valid email').max(255).required('Email is required'),
    password: Yup.string().max(255).required('Password is required')
  })}
  onSubmit={() => {
    login(email, password)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Authenticated: ', authenticated);
      if (authenticated === true) {
        navigate('/app/dashboard', { replace: true });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       // handle error
    })
  }}
>
```

Also rather than setting a variable `authenticated` outside a scope you can simply return from the login function and use it in the promise success handler.

```js
const login = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    console.log('User: ', user);
    return true
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
    throw error
  }
};
```

```js
  onSubmit={() => {
    login(email, password)
    .then((isAuthenticated) => {
      console.log('Authenticated: ', isAuthenticated);
      if (isAuthenticated === true) {
        navigate('/app/dashboard', { replace: true });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       // handle error
    })
  }}
```

Please read and understand more about javascript promises, asynchronous javascript and how they work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise